# Multiple import of xml metadata catalogues into GeoNode

Tags: postgis, metadata, geonode, pycsw

In our GeoNode's database (Postgis), we have imported many shapefiles using the tool shp2pgsql and then the command manage.py updatelayers. After that, we created their metadata catalogues from the INSPIRE editor:
http://inspire-geoportal.ec.europa.eu/editor/

Is it possible to import the xml metadata catalogues in GeoNode db without importing again the data ?

Comment: If you use GeoNetwork as csw you can do it through the GeoNetwork UI. but don´t know how with pycsw. Have a look at this. it may help. http://geopython.github.io/pycsw-workshop/docs/intro/intro-exercises.html#metadata-harvesting

Comment: @AN For thanks for your response ! I 'll check it out